# CountDownLatch await with timeout does not work in test case

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-asynctask, robolectric

I wrote a test case for my asyncTask as below. I found that the case still pass no matter what timeout I use in CountDownlatch await; even less than the sleep time in the asyncTask.

Can someone enlighten me why the await does not throw exception for exceeding timeout?

```java
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 3;
    }
}

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MyAsyncTaskTest {
    @Test
    public void doInBackground_shouldCompleteInTime() throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask() {
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
                assertThat(integer).isEqualTo(3);
                latch.countDown();
            }
        };

        task.execute();
        latch.await(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // not throw exception, why?

        assertThat(latch.getCount()).isEqualTo(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read a documentation? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#await(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)
```If the specified waiting time elapses then the value false is returned. If the time is less than or equal to zero, the method will not wait at all.```

Comment: I also tried using `assertThat(latch.await(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)).isTrue();` to see if it return false, but it doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure `task.execute()` starts a new thread? Please add ```System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());``` in ```onPostExecute``` and in test method. Is the output different or the same?